# How to download images from live XML feed to my PC

Tags: xml, download

I have a live XML feed from my CRM and it contains all the listing as well as the url for the images.

I want to download the images to my pc (local disk) with folder names (which will be the listing unique code)

I'm looking for something like listing 1 > folder > images inside and so on

https://positive.mycrm.com/feed/privatesite/a562eccfaba8c9d91039b7928937bc37 t

this is the feed I'm talking about

and software which can do this?

Answer (score -1):

```
$path="https://positive.mycrm.com/feed/privatesite/a562eccfaba8c9d91039b7928937bc37";
$xmlfile = file_get_contents($path);
$ob= simplexml_load_string($xmlfile);
$json  = json_encode($ob);

$configData = json_decode($json, true);
print_r($configData['property'][0]['photo'])
```

```
Response: 

Array
(
    [url] => Array
        (
            [0] => https://s3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/mycrm-pro-accounts-v2/property/full/1172/BqVpzbEh2kOWlhdv.jpeg
            [1] => https://s3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/mycrm-pro-accounts-v2/property/full/1172/mMeCvbqcKW30XnlU.jpeg
            [2] => https://s3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/mycrm-pro-accounts-v2/property/full/1172/doH3A7Z31OK1Q5JJ.jpeg
            [3] => https://s3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/mycrm-pro-accounts-v2/property/full/1172/ZxHi3BXiKGbLBpz5.jpeg
            [4] => https://s3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/mycrm-pro-accounts-v2/property/full/1172/bFKmsIRd01jkuyr1.jpeg
            [5] => https://s3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/mycrm-pro-accounts-v2/property/full/1172/iSXJTW7PvRVzxZ5i.jpeg
            [6] => https://s3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/mycrm-pro-accounts-v2/property/full/1172/3c2RR8WzlRq3XcRc.jpeg
            [7] => https://s3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/mycrm-pro-accounts-v2/property/full/1172/pshK7VL3N6MUEG3x.jpeg
            [8] => https://s3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/mycrm-pro-accounts-v2/property/full/1172/RQV5oQWNi3pvZF28.jpeg
            [9] => https://s3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/mycrm-pro-accounts-v2/property/full/1172/n2B940n5PPKjG0Bm.jpeg
        )

)
```